# matchedGeometryEffect on ScrollView memory leaks

Tags: memory, swiftui, scrollview, lazyvgrid

Im using a LazyVGrid to show an article gallery.
Everything is working fine, and I have no memory warnings, because every time a view leaves screen, memory usage is reduced.

My problem is when I use *matchedGeometryEffect* with the image, in order to sync animation with a new View.

Animation works perfect, but the memory is increasing while the scrollview is scrolling.
Is like if *matchedGeometryEffect* was maintaining the memory reference to the object, and don't  allow releases.

The container

```
LazyVGrid(
    columns: [
     GridItem(.flexible())
    ],spacing: 16
 ){
                    
   ForEach(viewModel.articles){ article in
        LazyVStack{
            ArticleCardView(article: article, animation: animation, show: $show)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.spring()){
                   selectedArticle = article
                   show.toggle()
                }
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

The cardView

```
VStack{
        if !show {
            Image(uiImage: readImage(name: "\(article.id)00"))
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                //.matchedGeometryEffect(id: "img\(article.id)00", in: animation)
```

...

The new view

```
VStack{
    GeometryReader { geo in
       TabView {
           Image(uiImage: readImage(name: "\(article!.id)00"))
               .resizable()
               .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
               //.matchedGeometryEffect(id: "img\(article!.id)00", in: animation, isSource: false)
               .tag(1)
```

...

Everything works perfect, but if I uncomment commented lines, memory usage increases when scroll.

Any idea?
Than you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I just embed the view into VStack and memories is released:

```
...
ForEach(viewModel.articles){ article in
     VStack{
        ArticleCardView(article: article, animation: animation, show: $show)...
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, could you share more code please ?